# Dnn 7 and MVC modules?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

Looking around I see a lot of documentation or articles for developing MVC based modules in Dnn 8 and up, but i see nothing for Dnn 7.

Is MVC module development supported in Dnn 7 and if so does anyone have links to some decent documentation on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported in DNN 7.

I would definitely recommend upgrading

Comment: We're not quite ready to go to version 9, but would version 8 fully support MVC modules?

Comment: If you're ready for 8, I highly recommend skipping it and going to 9. The support and enhancements for MVC in DNN9 are well worth it

Comment: My concern with v 9 is that it seems to be quite a huge shift from previous versions. I noticed certain elements/features have been removed etc., but I haven't had the time to fully test it in terms of upgrading one of our current projects and seeing what happens. 

Is there definitive guide to show the differences between v9 and previous versions?

Comment: You won't be disappointed with version 9. I only had one upgrade issue regarding the use of a Console Module. Everything else upgraded perfectly!